# For loop doesn't return any value using print() function

Tags: r

I used for loop to iterate the print() function to print values from 1 to 100. This is the code that I used

```
for(i in 1:100){
  print(i)
}
```

However, this code didn't return any value. When I use cat() function instead, it returned a value like this

```
for(i in 1:100){
  cat(i)
}

#Output: 123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930313233343536373839404142434445464748495051525354555657585960616263646566676869707172737475767778798081828384858687888990919293949596979899100
```

Is there something wrong with my for loop? Or maybe there is something that I need to check in my Rstudio?
P.S. This is what it looked like in my Rstudio
[image]

Comment: What do you get if you just type `print` in the console? Is it possible you’ve shadowed the built in function?

Comment: I am going to guess that something has overwritten `print`. `rm(list = ls());file.remove(".RData");file.remove(".Rhistory");` and then restart R. Note this removes the history and variables from your R session on next start up. Possibly something is obvious in your environment variables.

Comment: When I type ```print``` in the console, it returned:
```function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("print")
<bytecode: 0x0000020a5ba886a8>
<environment: namespace:base>``` . I tried the code in Rstudio Cloud and it worked, so maybe there's something wrong with my local Rstudio @MrFlick

Comment: I tried 
```for(i in 1:100){
  base::print(i)
}```
And it worked! Does it mean there is another package that has the ```print()``` function?  I haven't load any other packages, though... @MrFlick @Oliver

Comment: @MatthewFarant That is very surprising. Are these the first commands you run in a new session? You haven’t run `sink` or anything else that would redirect output? Thanks is just a normal script or code in the console and not a notebook or anything?

Comment: I already did ```rstudioapi::restartSession()``` first before I tried the code again. Yes, it's a normal script @MrFlick

Comment: I tried to delete my history and variables and finally it worked, thank you! @Oliver

Comment: If the output of `print` and `base::print` are the same (and they sound like they are), I can't see how you could possibly get different behaviors in the loop. Something doesn't seem right. Removing history shouldn't make a difference. And removing variables would have only helped had you defined an alternate `print()` function.

Comment: It could be that `print.default` has been overwritten as well. Which would be highly unexpected. If this was found in a cran package, although I'd say unlikely, I would report the behaviour to the dev team. Glad I could help however. :-)

Comment: Yes, I understand. I checked my environment before I deleted my history, and I have no variables/other functions/objects that labeled as ```print```. So, this is a bit strange... @MrFlick

Comment: @Oliver how would changing `print.default` only affect `print()` and not `base::print()`? Both functions would still dispatch -- they should find the same `print.default`. Even if you added `print.integer` or something, both have the `UseMethod("print")`

Comment: That is indeed true @MrFlick, didn't grant every comment equal amount of thought process. It is odd, and I would love if a reproducible example came into existence. Maybe a flag was set somehow.

Comment: To redefine `print.default <- function(x) invisible(x)` would affect `base::print`, like @MrFlick said. To get the normal behavior an explicit call to the *method*, `base::print.default(i)`, is needed.